# SoundCloud HTML5 Widget - How do I handle errors, particularly 404 "sound not found"

Tags: html, api, soundcloud, web-widget

I am integrating SoundCloud into my site and using the HTML5 player widget.

My site creates playlists and auto advances.

I am running into the following problem in testing.

Some sounds rather than playing result in the HTML5 widget displaying the message, "404 Error: Ooops this sound could not be found"

I also use the YouTube API and they have an onError event that makes it easy to handle errors and in my particular case skip to the next track in a playlist.

I have scoured the documentation and StackOverflow and I am surprised to see there is no mention of how to handle this common use-case for SoundCloud.

I do use event binding on the SC HTML5 widget but there is no mention of an error event??

So the question is specifically how can I trap the 404 and then execute custom code?

Thanks very much for an awesome API!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your feedback, unfortunately you are right and there's no such hook in the Widget API right now, we have added this feature request to our tracker.

Comment: Thanks so much. I must be the only programmer creating custom playlists with SoundCloud because this would have stopped any other similar app in its tracks. I hope you guys make this Priority #1 for your next patch/rollout as my OCD beta testers keep bringing this to my attention over & over & over... :))

Comment: @gryzzly it has been about over 9 months since this issue was pointed out. I'm facing the same problem currently. Are there any plans to fix this? Can you recommend a workaround?

Comment: Hey @james-berlin, there's now an onError handler which lets you handle problems like 404. http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events

Comment: @gryzzly I was already listening for ERROR events and it wasn't catching the 404, that's why I had to use the workaround I wrote. If you want to try it yourself here is the embed code I was using <iframe width="100%" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F137783801&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" class="embed" id="SCwidget"></iframe>

Comment: @James, this issue has be fixed and now proper Error event is fired when widget cant load audible: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and came up with a workaround for it. I initialize the widget inside a function and do setTimeout() at the beginning of the function and clearTimeout() on the play or error events, that way if the track plays or throws an error I can handle it with the event listeners and if it doesn't I can handle it with the function inside setTimeout().

```
function createSoundcloudWidget() {
    var soundcloudTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        onError();//the function to call when you get an error that doesn't throw an event
    }, 3000)
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#SCwidget');
    WIDGET = SC.Widget(iframe);

    WIDGET.bind(SC.Widget.Events.ERROR, function(eventData) {
        clearTimeout(soundcloudTimeout); //clears timeout
    }
    WIDGET.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function(eventData) {
        clearTimeout(soundcloudTimeout); //clears timeout
    });
}
```

It's not perfect but it will enable you to perform a function on any tracks that don't render a widget.

Answer (score 0):

SoundCloud HTML5 widget supports SC.Widget.Events.ERROR event today.

Errors can be caught with:

```
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.ERROR, function() {
 // error handling
});
```

Error event doesn't provide error message or other details as far as I know.

Comment: The 404 error does not throw a widget error event, this solution does not work to solve the problem.